# Ionic 3 popover on select, how to use of check icon instead of circle?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, html-select, popover

I tried to put it like this, like on the example

```
  <ion-col col-md-6>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Type</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="userType">
          <ion-option value="1">Type 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="2">Type 2</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
```

but the output is not similar on the example on the ionic documentation.
here is the output
[image]

I want something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually a platform issue: Ionic styles elements according to the platform you are running on. See the docs on this [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/).

You can also easily reproduce your issue viewing the [ion-select docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/) and changing between iOS and Android.

iOS output:

[image: iOS ion-select]

Android output:

[image: Android ion-select]

---

So assuming your developing for the iOS platform you don't have to change anything in your app to get the look you want. Once you deploy your app on an iOS device everything will look as you expect.

While testing your app in browser (I'm assuming Chrome, other browser might have the same feature) you might want to use the dev tools (F12) and [toggle the device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/#toggle). There you can [choose to see the viewport of a iPhone or iPad](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports#viewport-controls) and after refreshing the page (F5) you should see the correct controls.